# (discord.js) TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined when trying to send a direct message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have two text files, one with discord usernames with #, and another with the same amount of unique urls. I'm trying to make a discord bot to send each person one of the unique urls. I have run into an issue trying to send a test dm to one person. I keep getting the error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

```js
    // Require the necessary discord.js classes
    const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
    const { token } = require('./config.json');

    // Create a new client instance
    const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

    // When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready');
        client.users.cache.get('877248726085828720').send('yo');
    });

    // Login to Discord with your client's token
    client.login(token);
```

Comment: get('877248726085828720') is returning undefined, you sure this exists?

Comment: @alkhatim I copied it straight from my discord "Copy ID" I'm not sure why it also returns undefined for me too.

Comment: the  client.users.cache has a method called .each use it and log all the users and check for the one you want

Comment: Are you sure, that the user is in the cache?

Comment: @doc.Chocholoušek how do I check if they are in cache

Comment: As @alkhatim mentioned, you can list the cache with .each, or you can just simply console.log the whole cache, but it can be quite long based on how many users the bot can see.

Comment: @doc.Chocholoušek Hello I was able to display the cache but it only lists a few members in a certain testing channel how do I add the entire server to cache.

Comment: @AndrewSimon, there are only members, that the bot saw in some event. If you want to access someone, that isn't in the cache, you have to use fetch. Fetch also adds the member to the cache btw. It may also be a good idea to first look into the cache if it contains the member and fetch him only if not.

Answer (score 0):

Soo at the begining I think that you lose one intend so search them in
API Documentation Discord.js
Second I don't really understand where yiu want to send message but it should look like this

```
client.channels.cache.get('idhere').send('message');
```

I hope that helps you. Give me feedback if it does.